# trouble with using list comprehensions & input()

Tags: python, list, input, list-comprehension

Trying to write a list comprehension that can iterate through a string from input() and create a list with each character of the string having it's own index.

In essence, I want a function that does this:

```
x = ["00.00"[h] for h in range(len("00.00"))]
print(x)
> ['0', '0', '.', '0', '0']
```

When putting an actual string ("00.00") in there, python does exactly what I want it to do. But it refuses to take an input() the same way:

```
>>> x = [input()[h] for h in range(len(input()))]
> what

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <listcomp>
IndexError: string index out of range
```

The word "what" in there is what i inputted, but it does the same for basically everything else I've put in. I'm not sure what's so different about input() that changes how the indexes work. What is it?

Comment: store the result of `input()` in a variable or it will be executed at each iteration...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You produced a rather long-winded spelling of `list()`. There is no need to use list comprehension here:

```
list(input())
```

What goes wrong for you is that the expression at the front of the list comprehension is evaluated *for every single iteration*; so you call `input()` first to get a string, then  for every character in that string you call `input()` *again*, but this time the input is not necessarily the same string.

If you ever do need a list comprehension over a string, just iterate over the string directly. The Python `for` loop is a [*for each* construct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreach_loop), there is no need to generate an index; for example, to filter the input to produce a list of lowercase ASCII letters, there is no need to use `range()`:

```
[char for char in input() if 'a' <= char <= 'b']
```

Comment: I'm a super-huge newbie at this still, and I've gotta be honest with you before today I didn't understand how list comprehensions worked. Forgot this function existed. Thanks.